# How to get Amazon s3 url after upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, filepicker.io

In my users model filepicker_url is set to `https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/e7v43btpRbWG8zfj1xxx`

But I would like to just reference the file directly from Amazon s3. How do I get the Amazon s3 url?

Looking for something more like `https://<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com/<key>`

Comment: The key should be in the json response from the api.

Answer (score 1):

If you head to your S3 interface on the AWS backend, and click on the bucket--the left pane will show some tabs associated with the bucket.

Click on the Static Web Hosting tab and you'll be able to see your "Endpoint" address which will look something like the URL you said above...That will be the Amazon S3 URL you're using

Comment: Thanks. I am looking to integrate it into my application. After the upload I need to store the URL...

Answer (score 1):

When Ink Filepicker pick returns, it returns an InkBlob: https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/web/#pick

An example here:

```
{"url":"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/O3vnpPInTj2W60pAxLWq",
"filename":"imagephd.jpeg",
"mimetype":"image/jpeg",
"size":1003582,
"key":"Bhp0o65ySpCJ2B2R26lF_imagephd.jpeg",
"isWriteable":true}
```

If you have s3 enabled, then you'll see an entry called `key` which will have the s3 key. You'll just need to append the s3 url to the front, eg. `http://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKET_NAME/`

Comment: Can you explain what it means that "Filepicker returns an InkBlob"? Does that mean I now have a variable called InkBlob that I can manipulate? e.g. on a signup form when a user uses the Filepicker browser to upload something